# Why mapping filtered array of objects is not rendered using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to programming. I want to display the list of filtered users in a dropdown.

Below is what I am trying to do,
when user types '@' in the input field I get the string after '@' and use that string to filter the one that matches from user_list.
But this doesn't show up in the dropdown.

Say, user types '@', but it doesn't show the dropdown with user list.

Could someone help me fix this? thanks.

```
class UserMention extends react.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text='',
            user_mention=false,
        };
        this.user='';
    }
    get_user = s => s.includes('@') && s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('@') 
    + 1).split(' ')[0];

    user_list = [
       {name: 'user1'},
       {name: 'first_user'},
       {name: 'second_user'},
    ];

    handle_input_change = (event) => {
        let is_user_mention;
        if (event.target.value.endsWith('@')) {
            is_user_mention = true;
        } else {
            is_user_mention = false;
        }

        this.setState({
            is_user_mention: is_user_mention,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
        this.user = this.get_user(event.targe.value);
    }  

    render = () => {


    const user_mention_name = get_user(this.state.text);


    console.log("filtered_users", filtered_users);
        return {
            <input
                required
                name="text"
                value={this.state.text}
                onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                type="text"/>
                {this.user &&
                    <div>
                       {this.user_list.filter(user => 
                           user.name.indexOf(this.user) 
                           !== -1).map((user,index) => (
                              <div key={index}>{user.name}
                              </div>
                           )) 
                        }
                   </div>
               }
           );};}
```

Comment: Hello, there are multiple typos and errors in the provided code snippet that prevent it from running properly. Please, try fixing them and it will narrow your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `this.state.user_mention` is **always** false. In `handle_input_change` you set `is_user_mention`, but in render you check `user_mention`. Could this possibly be the issue?

Since `user_mention` is false, the expression will short-circuit and not render the list.

Comment: seems that's the issue. so i have edited my question with using this.user as conditional check. now it shows the filtered list in dropdown but when user types @ this.user is empty and doesnt show the list with all users. could you help me fix it. thanks

Comment: I think changing `is_user_mention` to `user_mention` (both the property and the variable) and still using it to conditionally render would be the solution